# not found: value expectMsg

Tags: scala, akka

I have the following test for an Akka component:

```
import somePackage.SomeActor
import akka.actor.{ActorSystem, Props}
import org.scalatest.{FlatSpec, Matchers}

class SomeActorSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers {

  val system = ActorSystem()
  val someActorRef = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[SomeActor]))


  it should "check the id" in {
    someActorRef ! CheckIfJobIsRunning(UUID.randomUUID)
    expectMsg(SomeOtherMessage(List()))
  }

}
```

I get the error:

```
 not found: value expectMsg
[error]     expectMsg(SomeOtherMessage(List()))
```

I have two questions:

1.How can I use `expectMsg`?

2.Where do I define, `SomeOtherMessage`, which should be received by the test class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `TestKit` scope. Your example should look like:

```
class SomeActorSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers {
  it should "check the id" in new Scope {
    someActorRef ! CheckIfJobIsRunning(UUID.randomUUID)
    expectMsg(SomeOtherMessage(List()))
  }

  abstract class Scope extends TestKit(ActorSystem()) {
    val someActorRef = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[SomeActor]))
  }
}
```

More info in [docs](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.0/akka/testkit/TestKit.html). Regarding your questions:

1. Use `expectMsg` to test that actor sends `SomeOtherMessage` to some other actor when it receives `CheckIfJobIsRunning`
2. Define `CheckIfJobIsRunning`, `SomeOtherMessage` and others in some Protocol-like file which contains all messages related to your actor. I personally use companion object of actor to specify all these messasges.